# decodeURIComponent dose not work from URL

Tags: javascript

i just tried  to decode a variable from URL but thats not gonna work when its reading from variable.

the current URL is :
http://localhost:2531/members.aspx?Mcat=1&searchType=fname&fname=%u0645%u06cc%u0631%u0632%u0627

```
        //this function
        function SetSearchItems() {
            try {
                var WinLOC = String(window.location.toString());
                WinLOC = WinLOC.replace(/%/g, '\\');
                var fname = String(getParameterByName("fname", (WinLOC)));

                //i want see decoded text for fname variable...       
                alert(decodeURIComponent(fname));
            }
            catch (err) {
                alert(err);
            }
        }


    function getParameterByName(name, url) {
        if (!url) url = window.location.href;
        name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
        var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
            results = regex.exec(url);
        if (!results) return null;
        if (!results[2]) return '';
        return decodeURIComponent(encodeURI(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " ")));
    }
```

as i mention on code , i want to see [fname] variable show decoded but it show : \u0645\u06cc\u0631\u0632\u0627
but thats not want i want to decode...

Comment: What is `getParameterByName`?

Comment: Can you give an example of the output you want from the `fname` parameter?

Comment: i want میرزا appear as result

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i found the solution , url has unicode value and i only need to convert it from unicode to normal text, so in this case decodeURIComponent dosent work really.

by this function that '\u0645\u06cc\u0631\u0632\u0627' may convert to normal text.

```
    function unicodeToChar(text) {
        return text.replace(/\\u[\dA-F]{4}/gi,
               function (match) {
                   return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(match.replace(/\\u/g, ''), 16));
               });
    }
```

thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/1497100/bryan-rayner

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't write your own URL parser: use [`URL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL), the built-in canonical URL manipulation API, which will let you automatically parse its [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) :

```
parsed = new URL("http://localhost:2531/members.aspx?Mcat=1&searchType=fname&fname=%u0645%u06cc%u0631%u0632%u0627")

parsed.searchParams.get("fname")
// returns "%u0645%u06cc%u0631%u0632%u0627"

decodeURIComponent(u.searchParams.get("searchType"))
// returns "fname"

decodeURIComponent(parsed.searchParams.get("fname"));
// Uncaught URIError: URI malformed
```

Your string was not encoded in a way compatible with [`decodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent), it looks like what `escape()` generates, which doesn't work:

```
decodeURIComponent(escape("میرزا"))
// Uncaught URIError: URI malformed
```

You instead want to use [`encodeURICompoenent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

```
decodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent("میرزا"))
// "میرزا"
```

So, to be clear, whatever you did to generate the text `"%u0645%u06cc%u0631%u0632%u0627"` is incorrect, you need to use whatever method will generate a URI component, which will look like `"%D9%85%DB%8C%D8%B1%D8%B2%D8%A7"`. (Perhaps that's not JavaScript, it's not specified in the question.)

Comment: well its work if i directly put my chars on decode method like this : decodeURIComponent('\u0645\u06cc\u0631\u0632\u0627') , but while its reading from variable its not gonna work.